# Safely redirect output to a single file with xargs parallel mode

Tags: xargs, parallelism

I have a bunch of bzipped JSON file that I read with xargs in parallel, do some light processing with `jq` and redirect the output to a file as follows:

```bsh
# Number of workers is one less than the number of cores
NUM_WORKERS=$(($(nproc) - 1))
NUM_WORKERS=$((NUM_WORKERS > 0 ? NUM_WORKERS : 1))

# List all bzipped files and process them with xargs in parallel
ls *.jsonl.bz2 | \
xargs -n 1 -P ${NUM_WORKERS} -I {} sh -c "bzcat | jq -c '{id,name}'" > output.jsonl
```

I have a 12 core processor and that they are all engaged when I run the command. However, I notice that the output from different workers gets mixed up in the output file:

```bsh
head -5 output.jsonl
{"id": "0", "name": "Name0"}
{"id": "1", "name": "Name1"}
{"id": "2", {"id": "3", "name": "Name3"}"name": "Name2"}
{"id": "4", "name": "Name4"}
{"id": "5", "name": {"id": "7", "name": "Name7"}"Name5"}
{"id": "6", "name": "Name6"}
{"id": "8", "name": "Name8"}
{"id": "9", "name": "Name9"}
```

I know I can write output from each worker to a separate temporary file and then concatenate them later, but is there a way to avoid the above without resorting to creating several temporary files?

Thanks!

Comment: GNU `parallel` serialises the outputs by storing them in temp files. I don't think there's any other way if you want them serialised. If you're happy for them to be mixed as long as lines retain their integrity (not interleaved), you could try running `jq` under `stdbuf -oL` for there be one `write()` system call per line.

Answer (score 2):

GNU Parallel creates tempfiles, but unlinks them immediately.

In practice this means that if the amount of data is small(ish) and the time for each job is small(ish) then these data never reach the disk (You can use `iostat -dkx 1` to see if it happens).

Since an unlinked file will not be recovered if the machine crashes, a smart file system can choose not to waste time on making sure these data are safely synced to disk in a consistent way. This can also make it faster.

You can also point `--tmpdir` to /dev/shm if you have enough RAM.

```
parallel "bzcat {} | jq -c '{id,name}'" *.jsonl.bz2 > output.jsonl
```

If you have plenty of CPU but not much RAM and a slow disk, it may be faster to compress the tempfiles:

```
parallel --compress "bzcat {} | jq -c '{id,name}'" *.jsonl.bz2 > output.jsonl
```

You do not need tempspace for all output - you only need tempspace for the currently running jobs. So if you run 12 jobs in parallel, you only need space for 12 files.